# How to specify rejectUnauthorized and PROXY information on same API call?

Tags: node.js, express, proxy

From my NodeJS - Express backend I need to call three different APIs:

1. **Scheduler On Premise API**: I was getting the following error: FetchError: request to https://bla.bla.bla/login failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain. I fixed this error using:

```
    const https = require("https");
    let httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
    });
    var requestOptions = {
        agent: httpsAgent,
        method: 'POST',
        ...
    };
    const fetchResponse = await fetch("https://bla.bla.bla/login", requestOptions)
```

2. **userList Cloud API**: I was getting the following error: FetchError: request to https://bla.bla.bla2/userList failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND bla.bla.bla2. I fixed this error using:

```
    # Setup an environment variable
    export HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@myproxy.server.com:port

    const fetch = require('node-fetch-with-proxy');
    const response = await fetch('https://bla.bla.bla2/userList');
```

3. **AZURE Token API**: I need the PROXY setup to be able to reach the API (that is working fine). I am getting the following error: FetchError: request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/111-222-333-444-555/oauth2/v2.0/token failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain.

   If I setup this variable: NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0, in my .env file, everything works fine, but that is not recommended. I want to set it up on specific calls only.

   If I do the following, I lose my PROXY setup and start getting this error: failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND login.microsoftonline.com

```
    # Setup an environment variable
    export HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@myproxy.server.com:port

    const fetch = require('node-fetch-with-proxy');
    const https = require("https");
    let httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
    });
    var requestOptions = {
        agent: httpsAgent,
        method: 'POST',
        ...
    };
    const response = await fetch('https://login.microsoftonline.com/111-222-333-444-555/oauth2/v2.0/token', requestOptions);
```

I haven't been able to use PROXY setup and rejectUnauthorized: false on the same API call. Do you have any clue how to resolve this?

Frustrating thing is that I can call my **AZURE Token API** with Postman without any issue...

Thanks in advance.